# Pivottable on SSAS cube: hide rows without result on measure

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssas, pivot-table, olap-cube

I'm having trouble hiding rows that have no data for certain dimension members for the selected measure, however there are rows for that member in the measuregroup.

Consider the following datasource for the measuregroup:

```
+---------+----------+----------+----------+--------+
| invoice | customer | subtotal | shipping | total  |
+---------+----------+----------+----------+--------+
| 1       | a        | 12.95    | 2.50     | 15.45  |
| 2       | a        | 7.50     |          | 7.50   |
| 3       | b        | 125.00   |          | 125.00 |
+---------+----------+----------+----------+--------+
```

When trying to create a pivottable based on a measuregroup in a SSAS-cube, this might result in the following:

[image]

However, I would like to hide the row for `Customer b`, since there are no results in the given pivottable. I have tried using **Pivottable Options -> Display -> Show items with no data on rows** but that only works for showing/hiding a Customer that's not at all referenced in the given measuregroup, say `Customer c`.

Is there any way to hide rows without results for the given measure, without creating a seperate measuregroup `WHERE shipping IS NOT NULL`?

*I'm using SQL-server 2008 and Excel 2013*

Edit:

For clarification, I'm using Excel to connect to the SSAS cube. The resulting pivottable (in Excel) looks like the given image.

Comment: Please show the query you are using at the moment...

Comment: @Shnugo: Since I'm using Excel to connect to the SSAS cube, I'm not using any query. I have made a note of this in the question since it seems that wasn't clear (enough).

Comment: @Aquillo is "shipping" a calculated measure of a physical measure. When you click on the blank shipping cell for customer B what do you see in the formula bar? What's your format string on the shipping measure?

Comment: @GregGalloway it is a physical measure, though if a calculated measure is necessary in this case, I will certainly consider it. Note that I'm hoping for a 'allround' solution for this, using the dimension `Customer` is a mere example. If what I'm asking is not possible and a custom calculation is needed for every case, than so be it, but at least I'll know.

Comment: @Aquillo can you answer all my questions above?

Comment: @GregGalloway the cell does not contain a function of some sort, it simply contains the numeric value provided by the SSAS cube. The FormatString for the measure is `#,##0.00;-#,##0.00`

Comment: @Aquillo so clicking on the blank shipping cell does not show a 0 (zero) in the formula bar. I was just checking if that cell had a value that was hidden by formatting. Are you sure there isn't a zero in the formula bar?

Comment: @GregGalloway It actually does show a zero in the formula bar

Comment: @Aquillo ah! Good. Edited my answer. That should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the DSV find the table with the shipping column and add a calculated column with expression:

```
Case when shipping <> 0 then shipping end
```

Please go to the properties window for the Shipping measure in the cube designer in BIDS and change the NullHandling property to Preserve. Change the source column to the new calculated column. Then redeploy and I am hopeful that row in your pivot will disappear.

And ensure Pivottable Options -> Display -> Show items with no data on rows is unchecked.

If that still doesn't do it connect the Object Explorer window of Management Studio to SSAS and tell us what version number it shows in the server node. Could be you aren't on the latest service pack and this is a bug.

Comment: Tried using Preserve as NullHandling property with the option unchecked. No changes, I think this is because there actually are rows for the given member, just not with values for the given measure. 

The version is 10.50.6000.34

Comment: The problem is that despite of the fact that there are no zero values in the sourcetable, that Excel still shows a zero. A quick query on `WHERE shipping = 0` does not give any results. The measure(group) is based directly on the table, there's no named query or expression in place.

Comment: @Aquillo if you comment out your whole MDX script except for CAlCULATE does it still say 0? Do you have where shipping is null rows? You did set NullHandling = Preserve right? Nulls get stored as 0 in SSAS unless you change that setting on the measure.

Comment: Greg, thank you very much for your help. It seems that the `NullHandling`-property has fixed the problem. It isn't clear to me why the previous test didn't fix it, but I guess it's due to the fact of reprocessing or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Go in your pivot table in Excel, click on the dropdown on your customer column. In the dropdown menu you will find an option called **Value Filters**. There you can set something like **Shipping greater than 0.1**.

This filters your Customer dimension column based on the measure values.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this (but I don't see the pivot...)

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(invoice INT,customer VARCHAR(10),subtotal DECIMAL(8,2),shipping DECIMAL(8,2),total DECIMAL(8,2));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,'a',12.95,2.50,15.45)
,(2,'a',7.50,NULL,7.50)
,(3,'b',125.00,NULL,125.00);

SELECT customer, SUM(shipping) AS SumShipping
FROM @tbl 
GROUP BY customer
HAVING SUM(shipping) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: This is SSAS not SQL